# Mapping complex types and field sizes

Tags: xslt

I have a xml document that I need to map a Description Field from the source xml document to a destination xml document with the following the criteria:

Source XML document Description field can have can a variable length 0 – 1000 chars.

The destination field has a complex type PID element (Invoice EDI in xml). Each instance of PID must have the character ‘F’ in PID01 and 40 characters placed in PID05 field. We need to generate enough PID elements to accommodate the full value of Field Description. Every PID05 should store 40 characters except the last PID instance which will have reminding symbols so it could be shorter.

[image: XML Messages]

Can anyone suggest how I would do this in xslt?

I assume we need to count the size of the description field, then divide that by 40 to get the number of PID element we need to create on the destination xml message, then copy each 40 character segment at a time putting the ‘F’ in PID01 and 40 characters in PID05?

Help much appreciated…

Cheers

Sample output is:

```
<PID>
  <PID01>F</PID01>
  <PID05>The quick </PID05>
</PID>
<PID>
  <PID01>F</PID01>
  <PID05>brown fox </PID05>
</PID>
<PID>
  <PID01>F</PID01>
  <PID05>jumped over</PID05>
</PID>
```

Comment: Can you show examples of the source and output xml?

Comment: Sorry about the delay folks, I have been travelling and had no Internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of your exact requirments, but you could make use of a recursive template to split your input text into **PID05** elements, each containing 40 characters.

For example, consider this element

```
<text>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</text>
```

Then, using the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:param name="splitLength" select="10"/>

   <!-- Pad out a string with excess characters -->
   <xsl:template name="pad">
      <xsl:param name="padChar" />
      <xsl:param name="count" select="$splitLength" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$padChar" />
      <xsl:if test="$count &gt; 1">
         <xsl:call-template name="pad">
            <xsl:with-param name="padChar" select="$padChar" />
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/text">
      <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="splitter">
      <xsl:param name="text"/>
      <PID>
         <PID01>F</PID01>
         <PID05>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1, $splitLength)"/>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($text) &lt; $splitLength">
               <xsl:call-template name="pad">
                  <xsl:with-param name="padChar" select="' '" />
                  <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$splitLength - string-length($text)" />
               </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
         </PID05>
      </PID>
      <xsl:if test="string-length($text) &gt; $splitLength">
         <xsl:call-template name="splitter">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, $splitLength + 1, string-length($text))"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the following is output

```
<PID>
   <PID01>F</PID01>
   <PID05>The quick </PID05>
</PID>
<PID>
   <PID01>F</PID01>
   <PID05>brown fox </PID05>
</PID>
<PID>
   <PID01>F</PID01>
   <PID05>jumps over</PID05>
</PID>
<PID>
   <PID01>F</PID01>
   <PID05> the lazy </PID05>
</PID>
<PID>
   <PID01>F</PID01>
   <PID05>dog       </PID05>
</PID>
```

Note I have parameterised the split length here, and set it to 10, not 40, just as an example.

Do not there is also a named template in there which pads out the last PID05 element to be the exact length (10 in this case).

Comment: Hey Tim, sorry for the delay and response, I put a sample of the output above, I think what you have is nearly there, I just need to be able to loop and create the PID complex block based on the size of the string mod 40, any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I've made a change, but I may have misunderstood, because you XML input sample seems to be missing the last bit of the text. Let me know if I am any closer then!

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have been travelling again and only got back to this, thanks!!